# Posting comment returns "NOT NULL constraint failed" error

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

My blog uses SQLite database blog.db with three tables:

```
class NewUser(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Registerd_new_user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    posts = relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="author")
    comments = relationship("comments", back_populates="user_name")

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "blog_posts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Registerd_new_user.id"))
    author = relationship("NewUser", back_populates="posts")
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    comments = relationship("comments", back_populates="posts")

class comments(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "commentz"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Registerd_new_user.id"))
    user_name = relationship("NewUser", back_populates="comments")
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("blog_posts.id"))
    posts = relationship("BlogPost", back_populates="comments")
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

db.create_all()
```

The post route where I populate `commentz` table with comments:

```
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_post(post_id):
    editor = CommentForm()
    requested_post = BlogPost.query.get(post_id)
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        new_comment = comments(text=editor.comment_text.data, author_id=current_user.id, post_id=requested_post.id)
        session.add(new_comment)
        session.commit()
    else:
        flash("You need to login first to See inside the post.")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template("post.html", post=requested_post, user=current_user, form=editor,
                           authenticated=current_user.is_authenticated)
```

/posts route gives this error:

```
[2023-07-06 13:23:52,126] ERROR in app: Exception on /post/1 [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: commentz.text

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ankit\Downloads\Starting+Files+-+blog-with-users-start\main.py", line 144, in show_post
    session.commit()
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 163, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1042, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 504, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 483, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2523, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2663, in _flush
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2624, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 586, in execute
    persistence.save_obj(
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 239, in save_obj
    _emit_insert_statements(
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 1135, in _emit_insert_statements
    result = cached_connections[connection].execute(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\ankit\PycharmProjects\oop-staring-project\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: commentz.text
[SQL: INSERT INTO commentz (author_id, post_id, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (2, 1, None)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jul/2023 13:23:52] "GET /post/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `editor.comment_text.data` before creating the `comments` object ? It seels that it is null